# Сборка python программы в exe файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, pyinstaller

Собираю pyinstaller'ом программу из под винды. Перехожу в корень проекта и запускаю команду

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.py
```

Выдает ошибку

```
125 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
125 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
125 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0
125 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Evilenzo\main.spec
140 INFO: UPX is not available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evilenzo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.3.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\users\evilenzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\evilenzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\evilenzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\evilenzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\evilenzo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'C:\Users\Evilenzo\main.py' not found
```

Comment: py2exe пробовали?

Comment: Запускаете точно из этой папки `C:\Users\Evilenzo`? И в этой папке есть `main.py`? Вообще ошибка явно говорит, в чем проблема..